# Adding the value of an element in an array to the value of another element in the same array

Tags: c#

I have

```
private static  int[][] board = Enumerable.Range(0, boardHeight).Select(n => new int[boardWidth]).ToArray();
```

and I want to add the value of

```
board[1][0]
```

to

```
board[2][0]
```

How do I do that?

Comment: `board[2][0] += board[1][0];`?

Comment: Yep that was what I was looking for :)

Comment: btw. simplify the initialialization to ``private static  int[][] board = new int[boardHeight][boardWidth];``

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be like that:

```
board[2][0] = board[2][0] + board[1][0];
```

or even shorter:

```
board[2][0] += board[1][0];
```